# Basic jquery mobile styling is not applied to dynamically added list items

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to create the list dynamically using jquery-mobile. I have ul as

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="bList"></ul>
```

I am dynamically adding list items to this  using template as :

```
<li id="someid" data-wrapperels="div" data-shadow="false" data-icon="false">
    <a href="#">some text</a>
</li>
```

After appending `li` to list I am calling

```
$('#bList').listview('refresh');
```

This creates the list and shows up. But the default jquery mobile styling for `li` is not shown. It shows read-only list as http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-readonly.html.

Also content is not wrapped in div inspite of `data-wrapperels="div"` being specified. I want the list to appear like http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/lists-ul.html.

I also tried displaying static list, but still the style is not applied.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: you add `ul` dynamically too?

Comment: no. 'ul' is already present. I am just appending 'li's dynamically.

Comment: this works normally http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/s423A/ how/when do you append items dynamically? Also, show libraries links in `head`. jQuery and jQuery Mobile versions you're using.

Comment: @sonam please add a fiddle

Comment: $('#bList').listview('refresh');
$('#bList').trigger("create");

Comment: Actually I am converting jquery site to jquery-mobile.
Files in header are:
'1. jquery.mobile-1.4.0-beta.1.css
2. jquery-1.8.2.js
3. jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js
4. jquery.mobile-1.4.0-beta.1.js
5. bootstrap.js
6. jquery.nanoscroller.min.js
7. jquery.validate.min.js?'

I also tried removing jquery-ui, as it might create some conflicts. But still I didnt get expected styling.

Comment: @Omar I modified your fiddle with different jquery-mobile versions. And I realised that such styles are never applied with jquery-mobile1.4 beta. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using JQM 1.4, instead of `.listview()` use `.enhanceWithin()`. Use jquery 1.9.x at least with JQM 1.4

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#bList').listview('refresh');
$('#bList').trigger("create");
```

Comment: Put first trigger then refresh
$('#bList').trigger("create");
$('#bList').listview('refresh');